# UITabBar titles are truncating after minimising and restoring my app

Tags: ios, uitabbar

I have an app with a UITabBar.

I'm using the `UITabBarAppearance` to configure it.

When I start the app, the tab items are correct:

[image: Tab Bar Item with correct title]

but when I minimise and then reopen the app they look like this:

[image: Tab Bar Item with truncated title]

Tapping on the tab bar items then restores them back to their original look i.e. the text is correctly drawn.

Any suggestions why this might be happening?

FYI The appearance code I'm using is this:

```swift
let appearance = UITabBarAppearance()
appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
appearance.shadowImage = nil
appearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.custom.navBackground

let textAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.custom.pink]
appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = textAttributes
appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.selected.titleTextAttributes = textAttributes
appearance.inlineLayoutAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = textAttributes
appearance.inlineLayoutAppearance.selected.titleTextAttributes = textAttributes

self.tabBar.standardAppearance = appearance
self.tabBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
```

Comment: have you checked the view hierarchy when you reopen the app and compare it with when it is correct first time or after the click ?

Comment: Yes - it's exactly the same, except the labels are truncated :(